# VLOOKUP - how to pick up several values and return TRUE if any of them fullfils a condition?

Tags: google-sheets

I am not an advanced user of google spreadsheet, apologize if the question is trivial.

I have a list of strings, which start with the same text "Title" and then there is a number:

Title1

Title2

Title3

etc.
They are in the column B

I don't have the last number defined, it changes dynamically.

For each of these strings I have a value assigned

Title1 = 3

Title2 = 5

Title3 = 4
etc.
the values are in the column C

I would like to know if **any** of these values meets a criteria.

So the logic is:

Search for any string in the column B which is "Title"&"*" and check its value in the column C. If any of these values is < 4, then returns "NOK". Otherwise returns "OK".

I have this formula:

```
=if(vlookup("Title"&"*", B:C, 2, false)<4)), "NOK", "OK")
```

For the above formula I always have "OK". As Title1=3, the result should be "NOK".

Thank you in advance
Zdzislaw

Answer (score 0):

*Can you try with:*

```js
=if(countifs(B:B,"Title"&"*",C:C,"<4"),"NOK","OK")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `min()` and `filter()`, like this:

```
=if(min(filter(C1:C, left(B1:B, 5) = "Title")) < 4, "NOK", OK")
```

See [min()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094017) and [filter()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093197).